# Neo4j with Python driver: number of nodes created is far less than expected?

Tags: python, neo4j, cypher

I am using a python script to retrieve some data from a SQL server, and create nodes in a neo4j server.

I used a `while` loop with **Cypher** statements to create the nodes one by one. The loop runs for ~37000 times(which is the number of rows of the table in SQL server), so I would expect there are as many nodes on neo4j server. However, there are only 943 nodes on the neo4j server. Any ideas please?

Here is the code:

```py
import pyodbc
from neo4j.v1 import GraphDatabase, basic_auth

# SQL part...#
cursor.execute(sqlQuery)  # retrieved data from SQL server..

print("let's connect to neo4j server....\n")
driver = GraphDatabase.driver("bolt://192.168.1.1:7687", auth=basic_auth("neo4j", "neo4j"))
session = driver.session()
print("now you've connected to server... :) \n")

j = int()
row = cursor.fetchone()
while row:
    j = j + 1
    msg = session.run("CREATE (:Person {name: '" + row[0] + "'});")  # Cypher
    row = cursor.fetchone()

print("total nodes created:",j)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried a defferent *Class* to run the **Cypher** statements, and this time everything worked just as I expected.

The idea is to create a *Transaction* to run multiple Cypher statements, and then commit at the end. Here is how I did it:

```
driver = GraphDatabase.driver("bolt://192.168.1.1:7687", auth=basic_auth("neo4j", "neo4j"))
session = driver.session()
print("now you've connected to server... :)")

j = int()
row = cursor.fetchone()

with session.begin_transaction() as tx:  
    while row:
        j = j + 1
        msg = tx.run("CREATE (:Person {Name: {n}});", {"n": row[0]})
        row = cursor.fetchone()
    tx.success = True  # commit the cypher statements

print("total nodes created:",j)
```

Now if I go back to the neo4j server to count the nodes, the number would be exactly the same as I expected.

One more thing, I noticed that the example code on [Neo4j Bolt Driver for Python](https://neo4j.com/docs/api/python-driver/current/#example) is not correct. Instead of **session.new_transaction()** the website suggested, we should use **session.begin_transaction()**.